# Telerik MVC Grid - Pass Value to New Controller Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, return-value, telerik-grid

Using Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC, I created the following Grid:

[image: Telerik MVC Grid]

.. and I am able to extract the value of my Order Number using the client-side event "OnRowSelect", when the user selects any item in the grouped order. I can then get as far as displaying the selected value in an alert but what I really want to do is pass that value back to a different controller action. Is this possible using javascript?

When I tried the server-side control, I ended up with buttons beside each detail row, which was just not the effect/look desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there is an easier way to get to the new page by simply changing the Window.location as follows:

```
var yourUrl = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'; 
var orderID;
function onRowSelected(e) {    
    var ordersrid = $('#IncompleteOrders').data('tGrid');        
    orderID = e.row.cells[1].innerHTML;        
    window.location = yourUrl + "?orderId=" + orderID;
}
```

Thanks to those who responded; however, the above answer as provided from Daniel at Telerik is more of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You  can easily make an ajax call in that event.
Kind of two part process (assuming your event handler resides in a separate .js file- otherwise you can define a url directly in .ajax call).
Define an url you need to post to -  in $(document).ready(...)
like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">           
$(document).ready(function() {      
   var yourUrl = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';           
});
```

Then place in your OnRowSelect event handler something like:

```
function onRowSelect(e) {
    var row = e.row;        
    var orderId = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url:  yourUrl,
        data: {id: orderId},
        success: function (result) {
            //do something
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
           //dosomething
        }
    });        
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: I think you need to add the 'accept' attribute to the $.ajax call.  "accept: application/json".  That will let MVC know that you sending it some json formatted data in the payload.

Comment: I think this should be sent in `Content-Type` header. `Accpet` is for the type of returned data.